# Does ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait types result in thread locking until entire result is consumed by client application?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, wait-types, waits

ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait types are mostly caused because the client application cannot process the data that arrives from SQL Server fast enough.

As the query executes, and as the results start getting available for consumption, the client application starts consuming the results. Assuming the result is held by say 4 threads, then, until the result is entirely consumed by the client application, do the threads that hold the data remain locked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming the result is held by say 4 threads, then, until the result is entirely consumed by the client application, do the threads that hold the data remain locked?

Not necessarily; it depends on the execution plan shape.

Result rows are assembled into packets for transmission to the client by the worker thread associated with the *parent task*. This thread will become blocked and wait on `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` if the client is slow to consume results. Only the parent task's worker returns rows to the client.

Additional parallel worker threads active in other areas of the plan run independently, and have no *direct* knowledge of the state of the parent task. They can, generally, continue to execute even if the parent task's worker is waiting.

That said, these parallel workers will eventually produce rows that need to be consumed by the parent task. When exchange buffers become full, the parallel workers will also experience waits like `CXCONSUMER` or `CXPACKET` until the parent task's worker resumes and reads rows from the exchange.

For more background on the *parent task* and how parallel execution works see my articles:

- [How MAXDOP Really Works](https://www.sql.kiwi/2020/07/how-maxdop-really-works.html)
- [Parallel Execution Plans – Branches and Threads](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/10/sql-plan/parallel-plans-branches-threads)
- [How Parallel Plans Start Up](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/03/sql-performance/parallel-plans-start-1)

Comment: I am assuming parent task is the one responsible to coordinate the child tasks, and that the child tasks are the ones that actually work on getting the data? Also, am I correct to say that the thread that is responsible to send data to the client is the 1st component's  (SELECT - query execution plan) thread?

Comment: @variable I added some reading for you at the end of my answer

Answer (score 4):

I like Paul White's answer about how async_network_io waits can result in parallel worker threads not able to continue working once parallel exchange buffers are full.

I'll answer from a different perspective, which hinges on what is meant by "do the threads... remain locked" in the question.

Other than parallel threads being unable to work while in cxpacket or cxconsumer waits, there is another important sense of parallel threads being "locked."  This is with respect to their potential of forcing a DOP downgrade for other parallel queries due to worker thread exhaustion.

As @variable has alluded in other posts, a simple DOP 8 parallel query might use 8 parallel workers, together with the parent execution context ID 0 for a total of 9 threads.  But a complex parallel query can have multiple plan zones execute concurrently - with each of those plan zones "getting" its own set of 8 parallel workers.  Some of the rowstore queries I work with at DOP 8 "get" 200 or more parallel workers.

So it's time to talk about different meanings of "getting" parallel workers.  Regardless of how many parallel workers are used at any given time by a DOP 8 query, they will be placed on no more than 8 schedulers. With default SQL Server behavior it can be hard to predict what schedulers those will be :-) Could be schedulers within the same auto soft-NUMA node, if auto soft-NUMA is enabled and DOP is less than the number of schedulers in the node. But might not be. Might be in the same SQL OS memory node which is usually aligned with hard NUMA nodes. But might not be. The execution context ID 0 thread for the DOP 8 query might be on the same scheduler as some of the parallel workers. But could also be on any other scheduler.

Bob Dorr documented this state of affairs...
[SQL Server Parallel Query Placement Decision Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-server-parallel-query-placement-decision-logic)

And Joe Obbish explored it here...
[Automatic Soft-NUMA and SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD Waits](https://orderbyselectnull.com/2018/04/17/automatic-soft-numa-and-sos_scheduler_yield-waits/)

So management of parallel threads can be complicated. SQL Server takes on the complexity of managing parallel threads and parallel queries with a pre-emptive reservation strategy. After a parallel query negotiates and receives it's memory grant - a memory reservation all of which may or may not be used - it negotiates and receives a parallel thread reservation. The query may or may not use the reserved number of parallel threads at any one time during its execution - the pre-emptive reservation is to prevent overcommitment.

How is the parallel thread reservation negotiated? SQL Server has a configurable for "Max worker thread count." All of the "qualifying" execution context ID zero threads are added to all current parallel query reservations. NOT the number of parallel worker threads bound to a task or "used", but reserved.  Also - the relevant session's own execution context ID 0 worker is already included in this count.

If the desired parallel worker reservation for the query at DOP 8 plus the sum above is greater than "Max worker thread count", the reservation request will go through DOP downgrade until the reservation plus the existing sum fit.  The parallel query could be downgraded all the way to DOP 1!  (It's guaranteed to be able to execute at DOP 1 because the session already has the execution context ID 0 thread to do so - it's the one negotiating.)

All right. Parallel worker reservation takes place before query execution.  When is the reservation released, and why the heck am I talking about this with respect to async_network_io waits?

Imagine a DOP 8 query, reserving 32 parallel workers, that returns 8 million rows to a client.  The query plan has a blocking sort at the end, so rather than streaming rows throughout it's execution the query basically returns all 8 million rows in a lump.  The query execution ends with 10 solid minutes of trying to get the 8 million result rows to the client.  It's only the execution context ID 0 thread returning the rows to the client. And over 99% of it's time is in async_network_io wait.  The 32 parallel worker reservation remains on the board until the last result row is sent.  That whole 10 minutes, the 32 worker reservation represents no actual load on the system.  But it contributes to the total liability when other queries are negotiating their parallel worker reservation and DOP.

In that sense, parallel worker threads - the reserved number of parallel workers which could result in DOP downgrade for other parallel queries - are "locked" until the last async_network_io wait of execution context ID 0 is over, and it has sent all result rows to the client.

I went through this long explanation because I believe in the cloud era, async_network_io waits are going to be the most doggone waits due to their front-loaded effects (contrbuting to DOP downgrades) and their back-loaded effects (dragging out query execution time at the end).

Comment: Looking at your example, once the threads have streamed all the rows into the blocking sort, then while and after the sort operation why do the threads that fetched the rows need to remain active? In this situation, is there any logic to why all thread reservation remains until the last result row is sent?